# TFS: Deploy same application to multiple geographic sites

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Using TFS I want to deploy the same web application to two different locations (West,Central). For this, I am trying to run phases concurrently to both locations using the `Run on multiple agents in parallel` option.

[image]

The following sample contains only one step `Deploy Website files`

[image]

Here my question.

How can I provide a different value for the `$(WebsiteServer)` variable based on the [multiplier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/test-with-unified-agent-and-phases#multiple-executions)?

I have tried to configure multiple variables in the environment.

[image]

And then use them like `$($(Location).WebsiteServer))` but that does not expand correctly.

I am thinking now on creating a custom task that will create variables at release time base on the hardcoded values and use those variables instead. But it seems hacky.

Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Make `WebsiteServer` your multiplier, then make the value a comma-separated list of the servers.

Comment: Well, that will work for this sample, but my actual scenario involve things like the service account to deploy to West is different than the service account to deploy to Central (I cannot change that and use a single account) so I need to be able to calculate those variables at release time.

Comment: Then use two different environments.

Comment: That does not help at all

Comment: How does it not help? You can have two environments with the same deployment conditions running on the same agent pool that will run your deployment in parallel. It's exactly what you're looking to accomplish, but without using (admittedly limited) multipliers. If you're worried about duplicating tasks across environments, then use task groups.

Comment: Well, my actual scenario is more complicated and there are some interdependencies among the region deployments (West, Central). By definition ` you must be able to deploy to an environment independently of other environments in the release definition`. And that is one of the constraints that phases are design to resolve. *It is a shame that tasks cannot expand inline expression parameters*.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some variables as followed.
[image]

WebsiteServer, User and Pass variables are some intermediate variables to store your WebsiteServer IP, User Name and Password.
You could configure your environment as followed.
[image]

You could add  a PowerShell Task to modify the values of WebsiteServer, User and Pass variables by logging command **"##vso[task.setvariable variable=variableName]variableValue”** from nested varialbes, such as $($(Location).WebsiteServer).

You could refer to the following powershell script:

[image]

Script:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=WebsiteServer]$($(Location).WebsiteServer)"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=User]$($(Location).User)"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Pass]$($(Location).Pass)"
```

You could use WebsiteServer, User and Pass variables in Copy files Task like the following.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I end up doing something similar using a custom task and the `Get-VstsTaskVariableInfo` function from https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib. I think this is cleaner since I don't need to define the placeholder variables instead I create them and assign the value base on the multiplier. Also, I have very good control over the secret variables so I can create them with `issecret=true` as well. If someone needs the complete script I can post it here as an answer.